# Beacon - eddystoneTlm Not Detecting by my code frequently

Tags: node.js, ibeacon, beacon

Beacon - eddystoneTlm Not Detecting by my code frequently.
its Detecting by Beacon mobile app @ 1 sec interval but by my code its detecting in about 15 min.

Here is my code -

```
const noble = require('noble');

// Create a Linking object
const BeaconScanner = require('node-beacon-scanner');
const scanner = new BeaconScanner({'noble': noble});
scanner.onadvertisement = (ad) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ad, null, '  '));
};

// Start scanning
scanner.startScan().then(() => {
  console.log('Started to scan.')  ;
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: What platform are you running this on?  Can you detect the same beacon on the same platform at a more frequent interval using an off the shelf program?

Comment: By using eddystone-beacon-scanner module ,I am able to ge tml data of beacon frequently.

Comment: While using eddystone-beacon-scanner module on mac Its working fine but on linux its not working frequently.What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Do anyone have any idea about this issue ?